# How can I make Internet Explorer not change the colors in my PNG images

Tags: html, internet-explorer-7, png, gamma

When using PNG files (made with Paint.NET) as background images on my web site, IE7 is changing the colors and actually displaying a darker version of my images, as seen [here](http://twitpic.com/bud1). In this image, the dark background and background image should be both #001122, and the medium background and background image #004466. But IE7 changes the images to #000C1A and #003A5B respectively. No problem with FF3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IE has a known bug with PNG gamma info, though I thought they had fixed it in version 7 :-?

I remove the gamma info from PNG files using "PNG Crush". I've created a right-click shortcut in Windows explorer. Further info: [using pngcrush in windows](http://www.weirdlooking.com/blog/64)

Comment: In this particular case, removing only the gamma section out of the PNG file is enough: pngcrush -rem gAMA inputfile.png outputfile.png

Thanks!

Comment: PNGGauntlet is a nice Windows GUI for PNGOUT that could also be used for removing the gamma from PNGs. http://brh.numbera.com/software/pnggauntlet/

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to PNGOUT is TweakPNG. Comes with a GUI and no installer, very easy to remove the gAMA (just right click and delete it!)

http://entropymine.com/jason/tweakpng/

Answer (score 2):

I think this has to do with Gamma correction.  Take a look at this

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GammaCorrectionAndColorCorrectionPNGIsStillTooHard.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Additional resource on this issue: http://www.modernblue.com/web-design-blog/tweak-that-gamma/